# SDL audio callback stops after two iterations

Tags: c++, linux, audio, sdl

Given the following code:

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_audio.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

static void SDLCallback(void *userData, Uint8 *data, int bytes) {
  std::cerr << "SDLCallback: " << bytes / sizeof(float) << "\n";
}

int main() {
  using namespace std::literals;
  SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_AUDIO);

  SDL_AudioDeviceID m_deviceId{};
  SDL_AudioSpec m_desired, m_obtained;
  m_desired.freq = 48000;
  m_desired.format = AUDIO_F32SYS;
  m_desired.channels = 2;
  m_desired.samples = 1024;
  m_desired.callback = SDLCallback;
  m_desired.userdata = nullptr;

  m_deviceId = SDL_OpenAudioDevice(nullptr, 0, &m_desired, &m_obtained, 0);
  std::cerr << "SDL device: " << m_deviceId << std::endl;
  if (m_deviceId < 2) {
    std::cerr << "SDL: Couldn't open audio: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
    exit(1);
  }
  
  std::cerr << "rate: " << m_obtained.freq << "\n";
  std::cerr << "samples: " << m_obtained.samples << "\n";
  std::cerr << "bytes: " << m_obtained.size << "\n";
  std::cerr << "channels: " << (int)m_obtained.channels << "\n";
  
  SDL_PauseAudioDevice(m_deviceId, 0);

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(100ms);
    std::cerr << (SDL_GetAudioDeviceStatus(m_deviceId) == SDL_AUDIO_PLAYING)
              << std::endl;
  }
  
  SDL_CloseAudioDevice(m_deviceId);

  SDL_Quit();
}
```

I am seeing the following output:

```
$ ./a.out
SDL device: 2
rate: 48000
samples: 1024
bytes: 8192
channels: 
SDLCallback: 2048
SDLCallback: 2048
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
<program gets stuck on SDL_CloseAudioDevice>
```

That is, the SDLCallback function is called only twice at the beginning then not anymore, yet the audio is still marked as running. I am using PulseAudio.
What can I do to prevent that ? Where is my program wrong ? It works if I kill PulseAudio, but PulseAudio works fine for all my other software.

And if it is not wrong, how can I make sure that my users will never encounter that issue  ? How can I recover without getting the program stuck on SDL_CloseAudioDevice ? As PulseAudio is very common among Linux users.

Comment: Can't repro on Kubuntu 20.04 with SDL 2.0.10.

Comment: For me it happens intermittently across reboots. If I restart pulseaudio it will sometimes work a bit then fail again after a few launches. Other audio apps like my music player are still working.