# C++: SDL audio callback eventually stops working

Tags: c++, windows, audio, sdl, sdl-2

I'm making an audio visualizer with, among others, SDL to record audio.

When I turn on audio recording, everything works fine for anywhere between 0 and 20 seconds, and then SDL stops making audio callbacks. I'm under the impression that this happens when there isn't any sound for a short period of time, but no matter how much noise I make, I can't prevent it.

Here is an outline of my code. There is a lot of it, so I'll omit things I think are working properly.

```
//(imports and stuff)
bool active = false;
Uint8* rawSamples = nullptr;
float* audioBuffer = nullptr;

int main() {
   init();
   active = true;
   while (active) {
       float* audio = getAudio();
       handleEvents();
   }

}

void init () {
    // (SDL Init, device selection, device opening)
    // dev: device ID returned by SDL_OpenAudioDevice, have: audioSpec of said device

    int rawSamplesSize = (int)have.samples * SDL_AUDIO_BITSIZE(have.format) * have.channels / 8;
    rawSamples = new Uint8[rawSamplesSize * 4];
    audioBuffer = new float[(int)have.samples];

    SDL_PauseAudioDevice(dev, 0);
}

void audioCallback(void* userdata, Uint8* stream, int len) {
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        rawSamples[i] = stream[i];
    }
}

float* getAudio() {
    SDL_LockAudioDevice(dev);
    for (int i = 0; i < have.samples; i++) {
        audioBuffer[i] = ((float*)rawSamples)[i];
    }
    *audioLengthPointer = have.samples;
    SDL_UnlockAudioDevice(dev);
    return audioBuffer
}

void handleEvents() {
    SDL_Event e;
    while (SDL_PollEvent(&e)) {
        if (e.type == SDL_QUIT) {
            active = false;
        }
    }
}
```

I have checked a few things:
The recording works properly.
The device stays active even when there aren't any callbacks.
It isn't a locking-unlocking problem.
Pausing-Unpausing doesn't seem to help.
The program keeps going, even without callbacks.
At the start, there are a few callbacks without any getAudio calls between them.

Note: I already know this question is similar to [SDL audio callback stops after two iterations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67951118/sdl-audio-callback-stops-after-two-iterations) but in my case I am recording audio, and the number of callbacks isn't fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Changing drivers has solved the problem.
Since the question now becomes why wasapi decides to stop sending audio data, which isn't quite related to SDL, I'm closing this question.